# FileUploadControl with no file system access

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, file-upload

Unfortunately, both OLEDB and FileUploadControl seem to want a path.

Right now, this works after a user has submitted an excel file but won't work on my server due to 0 file system access:

```
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath);
ConvertToCSV(filePath);
...
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", filePath);
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
```

I see FileUploadControl exposes a stream and a bytecode. Would it be possible to traverse the file with those properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)

I was able to read values from the stream no problem using the following code:

```
Stream myStream = MyFileUpload.FileContent;

IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(myStream);
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();

string r1c1Val = result.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Obviously my example is really simple but having the data as a DataSet should give you a lot of flexibility in how you read it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the OleDB won't work on streams...

IF you really want to access the Excel-file directly in-memory after upload then you will need some 3rd-party component (like Flexcel, Aspose.Cells, SpreadsheetGear...) which can load Excel files directly from memory (`FileUploadControl.FileBytes` or `FileUploadControl.FileContent`)...

Although not sure what `ConvertToCSV` does and whether it can work on memory...

Comment: ConvertToCSV is just uses OLEDB to traverse atm.